# BottomNavigationView is not showing more than 3 items

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

BottomNavigationView is not showing all of the items declared in menu.xml in android studio. this answer works only for android support 28 and up.

Answer (score 1):

For some developer that are having a hard time with this question, the answer for this is just add this xml code in your bottomnavigationview

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
"app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
 />
```